# Symfony 3 asset install output folder name for bundle

Tags: php, symfony, assets

Is there any way to define output folder name which will be generated for `symfony/src/mybundle/Resources/public` directory content ?

Right now it auto generates `web/bundles/`**mybundlename**`/css` folder, but i need to have
`web/bundles/`**custome_name**`/css`

PS: i searched in google did not found anything about this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Webpack and Encore as the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html) recomends you can edit the arguments in

```
Encore
// directory where compiled assets will be stored
.setOutputPath('web/bundles/yourcustomname/')
// public path used by the web server to access the output path
.setPublicPath('/yourcustomname')
```